# Multiple Taskbars

Tags: 16.04, panel, taskbar

[image]
[image]

I have two sets of taskbars. I want to remove the gray ones from the top and bottom of the screen and keep the black one at the top and the narrow black tray at the bottom. FYI, the gray one at the top is sometimes hidden by the black one. How can I get rid of them?

Running Ubuntu 16.04.4 xenial

Comment: Did you hold alt+right-click?? just saying....
Can't tell if that's Gnome 3 classic mode or MATE

Comment: @Robert Sederholm - Thanks for your suggestion - that worked for the bottom panel, but not the top one. After right-clicking, there appeared a context menu with the option to delete this panel, but for the top panel, that option is grayed out. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Following a comment posted to my question, I removed one of the gray panels with alt+right click and selecting "Delete this Panel".

For the last gray panel the option to delete was grayed out, so I looked into it and then did this:

```
killall gnome-panel
sudo mv /usr/bin/gnome-panel /usr/bin/gnome-panel.back
```

Running killall on the gnome-panel probably would have removed both panels making the first step (alt+right click) unnecessary.